# how to get the value of an "item" node

Tags: xml, powershell, nodes, selectnodes

I have thousands of .XML files that contain code similar to the following:

```
<work-item>
    <field id="assignee">
        <list>
            <item>John Doe</item>
            <item>AZCDEF</item>
        </list>
    </field>...
```

I am using the following Powershell to try to get the value of the "item" nodes:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\dev\workitems\ -include workitem.xml -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
$files | foreach {
    $Doc = [xml]$MyXML = Get-Content $_
    write($_)
    #write($Doc.name)
    $XMLNode  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//field[@id="assignee"]/list/item')

$XMLNode | foreach {
    If ($_.'#text'.length -ne 6) {
        write("Removing " + $_.'#text' + " From xml.")
        [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
    }
}
$Doc.Save($_)
```

}

However, I get the following error when saving the document:

> *Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Save'.
>   At C:\ALM\PowerShell Scripts\Remove bad assignee.ps1:14 char:14
>   +     $Doc.Save <<<< ($_)
>
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Save:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound*

The problem is I can't seem to get the value (John Doe or AZCDEF) of the item node so I can check its length and second character.

How do I save the document after I have removed the element?

Comment: write($_.'#text'.length) will give me the lenght of the node. its a start.

Comment: Hint: `$XMLNode | % { if($_."#text" -match ".z.{4}") {$_."#text"}  }`

Answer (score 0):

To get the text content of the node (incuding any child nodes) you can use the [InnerText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext?view=netframework-4.8) property:

```bsh
PS> $xml = [xml] @"
<work-item>
    <field id="assignee">
        <list>
            <item>John Doe</item>
            <item>AZCDEF</item>
        </list>
    </field>
</work-item>
"@

PS> $nodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//field[@id="assignee"]/list/item')

PS> $nodes | foreach { write($_.InnerText) }
John Doe
AZCDEF
```

And once you've got the string you can filter the value - e.g.

```bsh
PS> $nodes | where-object { ($_.InnerText.Length -le 2) -or ($_.InnerText[1] -ne 'Z') }

#text
-----
John Doe
```

Bearing in mind that strings are zero-indexed, so the second character is `$_.InnerText[1]`...

So now we've expression which filters the list of nodes to remove, and we can just pipe that into [RemoveChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild?view=netframework-4.8):

```bsh
PS> $nodes `
| where-object { ($_.InnerText.Length -le 2) -or ($_.InnerText[1] -ne 'Z') } `
| foreach-object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }

PS> $xml.OuterXml
<work-item><field id="assignee"><list><item>AZCDEF</item></list></field></work-item>
```

Comment: Ok, i got the code this far:$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\dev\workitems\ -include workitem.xml -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
$files | foreach {
    $Doc = [xml]$MyXML = Get-Content $_
    write($_)
    #write($Doc.name)
    $XMLNode  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//field[@id="assignee"]/list/item')

    $XMLNode | foreach {
        If ($_.'#text'.length -ne 6) {
            write("Removing " + $_.'#text' + " From xml.")
            [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
        }
    }
    $Doc.Save($_)   
}

Comment: Thanks, i will try that too. I found a way to get the lenght of the text using  .'#text' I have modified the code above with what I currently have. It seems to be working except I can't save the file.

Comment: Ok i got the InnerText to work, now its just getting the "save" to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following code.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\dev\workitems\ -include workitem.xml -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
$files | foreach {
    write($_)
    [xml]$MyXML = Get-Content $_
    $XMLNode  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//field[@id="assignee"]/list/item')

    $XMLNode | foreach {
        write($_.InnerText)
        If (($_.InnerText.Length -le 2) -or ($_.InnerText.Length -ne 6) -or ($_.InnerText[1] -ne 'Z')) {
            write("Removing " + $_.InnerText + " From xml.")
            [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
        }
    }
    $MyXML.Save($_)   
}
```

Comment: Followup question, some of the xml files contain only a single assignee and the format of the node is different (<field id="assignee">Steven Morey</field>). The following code doesn't return anything.                $singleAssignee  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//field[@id="assignee"]')
        write ("`t" + $singleAssignee.InnerText)

Comment: I also tried $singleAssignee  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//field[@id="assignee"]')
        write ("`t" + $singleAssignee.'#text") same result, no output